# Map with collection of values for a key

Tags: java, collections, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using protobuf, and in one of the models the structure is like this -

```
public class Model{
   int id;
   Map<Integer,Collection<Details>> details;
}
```

Corresponding protobuf message -

```
message ModelMsg{
     sint32 id;
     map<sint32,DetailsMsg> details;
}
```

How do I represent above model in protobuf format ?
I see there is "map" construct in protobufs - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps.

But does it support collection of values for a key ?
If I have to support such collection of values in protobuf format is there any solution ?

Comment: have you tried using `repeated`? something like `message DetailsMsg {
    repeated Details detailsMessage = 1;
}`

Comment: Create a wrapper proto with a repeated field for your collection like @mangusta said.